# Images getting deleted automatically from nodejs server

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have deployed a nodejs server on Heroku as free services. So, I have noticed that it only supports two image file to upload. I have an API in my project to upload an image. After upload it appears on my application or on my interface for sometime.

After 5 to 10 minutes images will delete automatically from the server only if it exceeded from two images. Just two images remain in the folder rest of the images will deleted automatically. So, I want to ask why this happen? Because of free deployment or any other reason?

Comment: You need to use a third party service to store your assets. Yes Heroku erase everything that is not part of your version control (git).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you upload an image to your Heroku server it is being stored in some tmp location and Heroku may free up that location periodically. So it is not persistent storage.

The more convenient way of storing images is to using AWS S3, google drive or any third party service which can guarantee persistency and availability

Comment: Okay Thanks I'll try.